# Raspberry Pi screen with 'quick release' GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi

Has anyone had any experience with interfacing a Pi with a HAT via GPIO pins that can quickly and reliably be 'detached' from the Pi. Im thinking something similar to a Super Nintendo Cartridge would connect with the console.

Answer (score 3):

I know this "clamp" but it requires an Raspberry without soldered pins.

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/flatmax/pcb-quick-connect-clip-40-pin-raspberry-pi-compati?ref=381495&token=5057c6fa